# SSL ошибка в тг python боте

Tags: python, aiogram

После небольшого перерыва(месяца 2) я вернулся к телеграм боту на питоне, запустил его и получил вот такую ошибку:
Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')]

Можете подсказать в чем может заключаться причина появления этой ошибки?

Comment: Видимо кто-то вмешивается в ваш интернет-трафик, например антивирус

Comment: Да, точно. Первый раз когда я получил эту ошибку, я сразу подумал на антивирус. Просто решил убедиться в своей догадке.